# Using PHP session variable to keep user logged into website

Tags: php

I want to assign a value to a session variable when a user logs into a website. I read that I must explicitly start a session at the top of my pages in order to do this. So I inserted:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
    echo "started";
}
```

The first thing I notice is that "started" is displayed every time I reload my page. Is that expected behavior? I would assume the second time I load the page, the session should already be there, therefore "started" would not display.

Further down in my page, I have:

```
$_SESSION['id']=2;
echo "<p>Your session ID is: " . $_SESSION['id'] . "</p>";
```

That correctly displays the ID in the "echo" statement. So even after assigning a value to a session variable, when I reload the page, it puts "started" at the top.

Am I doing something wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is expected behaviour, you need to call `session_start()` before any output is sent to the browser **every time** the page is loaded, which is why your echo is happening every time. You if statement in this case is a little unnecessary and you should just simply call it without the if.

```
session_start();
```

For example, a `$_SESSION` variable will never be accessible unless you call `session_start()`, despite the fact that it **will** exist in the browser's session. Calling `session_start()` simply allows you to access that superglobal array.

Answer (score -1):

You need to put your `session_start()` at the top of the file.
Otherwise you won't be able to use the `$_SESSION` array.